# Xades4j and Base64 in EnvelopedXmlObject

Tags: xades4j

I tried to insert Base64 string into Object in EnvelopedXmlObject:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);        
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = dBuilder.newDocument();  
    String generatedDocument = ...;

    BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    String generatedDocumentEncoded = encoder.encode(generatedDocument .getBytes("UTF-8"));
    Node node1 = document.createTextNode(generatedDocumentEncoded);
    DataObjectDesc dataObjectDesc = new EnvelopedXmlObject   (node1, "plain/text", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#base64");
    ....
```

When i run this code in file.xml each line of Object is ended with "&#13;" which cause an error with decoding text

When I add this lines:
  Node node1 = document.createTextNode(generatedDocumentEncoded);

```
saveFile("c:\\temp\\temp.xml", generatedDocumentEncoded);
String stringFromFile = read("c:\\temp\\temp.xml");
node1.setTextContent(stringFromFile);
```

then generated file is ok - where is my mistake ? :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that Base64 encoder You use will produce chunked output (put carriage returns in string). You can replace in output string this characters like below:

```
generatedDocumentEncoded = generatedDocumentEncoded.replaceAll("(\r\n|\n)", "");
Node node1 = document.createTextNode(generatedDocumentEncoded);
```

or force Your BASE64Encoder generate not chunked output.
I'm using for that [Base64](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/util/Base64.html) class from Apache Commons:

```
byte[] bytes = generatedDocument.getBytes("UTF-8");
String generatedDocumentEncoded = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(bytes, false), "UTF8");
```